# C++ equivalent to directly writing to screen in assembly

Tags: c#, c++

In 68000 assembly you utilised techniques to identify the screen address and then write your image to the screen.  I would like to know how this could be done using C++ or similar.  Can anyone help with this or point me at such a tutorial?

I used to develop small games/demos in 68000 assembly many years ago. I've recently taught myself c++ as well as playing with c#.  I appreciate there's openGL and Direct X available among many other libraries/engines that I could use to do the work for me but I'm simply interested in how I could essentially place a pixel not the screen at the lowest level within C++ or similar. Its less practical but more educational for me.

I'm assuming in a Windows environment I would be looking to use an OS API to do this but which?  Or is my answer actually openGL or DirectX.  If so, whats the best method to place a single pixel on an otherwise blank display?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: GDI32 API allows doing this: 'HDC screenDc = GetDc(NULL); SetPixel(screenDc, x, y, COLORREF)'

Comment: Scribbling over the desktop is probably not best practice, so if you're not looking for a 3D-type technology you should also learn about how to open your own window to draw in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphics is not part of standard C++. You have to use 3rd party libraries to do this. There are several choices. You already mentioned OpenGL and DirectX, which I consider quite low-level. If you want to go even lower level, you can use the API given by your OS.

Comment: That's the answer I was thinking.  What's the API used for Windows and OS X?

Comment: @GavinBrennan Windows has the the Windows API (shocking?) -- often abbreviated as "WinAPI" -- which is what [@Slava's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798705/c-equivalent-to-directly-writing-to-screen-in-assembly/25798945?noredirect=1#comment40353255_25798705) uses. OS X has its own API which I am not familiar with.